# музыка в python

Tags: python, консоль, музыка, плеер

Я захотел, что бы в моей консольной программе python играла музыка на фоне, но не смог этого сделать!
Я попробовал такие варианты кодов:

```
1)

import pygame
pygame.init()
song = pygame.mixer.Sound('file.mp3')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
song.play()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()


2)

import pyglet
song = pyglet.media.load('file.mp3')
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()


3)

import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst
import gobject
import os

mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
pl = gst.element_factory_make("playbin", "player")
pl.set_property('uri','file://'+os.path.abspath('file.mp3'))
pl.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
mainloop.run()
```

Но ни один не сделал нужное, либо музыка проигрывалась, и только после этого программа запускалась, либо оно всё крашилось, либо музыка не играла вообще! Форматы и качество музыки менял, не помогало, все нужные библеотеки установленны.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import pygame, pygame.mixer, time
from pygame.locals import *


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()            
        self.game_start = True   
        self.window_width = 1200 
        self.window_height = 600 
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.window_width, self.window_height)) 
        self.background = pygame.image.load("img/background.jpg")                     # !!! 
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (self.window_width, self.window_height)) 

        ... 

        # МУЗЫКА
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.set_reserved(0)
        self.game_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/game_music.wav")                 # !!! 
        pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(self.game_music,-1)

        # FPS
        self.fps = pygame.time.Clock() 

        # LOOP 
        self.game_init = True
        while self.game_init:
            self.fps.tick(30) 
            for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    
                ...

            self.window.blit(self.background,(0,0))    
            pygame.display.update()
            
Game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё норм, но! программа запускается в консоли!